# How Can I Check nginx load?

Tags: nginx

How can I check the current load on my nginx server?

Comment: `top`, `iotop`, `netstat`, and `htop` are good places to start

Answer (score 5, accepted):

nginx has a status module ([NginxHttpStubStatusModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpStubStatusModule)) that you can access via:

```
http://yoursite/nginx_status
```

but you need to recompile nginx to get this support - it isn't enabled by default.

See [this blog post](http://kovyrin.net/2006/04/29/monitoring-nginx-with-rrdtool/) for more details.